# Split a string on capitals and digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currentl using 
`thing.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");` to split a string on capitals like so.

HereAreSomeWords ======  Here Are Some Words

SomeMoreStuff ====== Some More Stuff

I'd like to update the regex so that it will split on groups of numbers as well.  So the desired output would be:

123SomeWords ========  123 Some Words

Some1Words =======     Some 1 Words

Some1234Words =======     Some 1234 Words

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: What are your thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the pattern:

```js
/([a-z\d](?=[A-Z])|[a-zA-Z](?=\d))/g
```

and replace it with this:

```js
"$1 "
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var tests = new Array(
  "HereAreSomeWords",
  "SomeMoreStuff",
  "123SomeWords",
  "Some1Words",
  "Some1234Words"
);

for (var i in tests) {
  print(tests[i] + " -> " + tests[i].replace(/([a-z\d](?=[A-Z])|[a-zA-Z](?=\d))/g, "$1 "));
}
```

which prints:

```
HereAreSomeWords -> Here Are Some Words
SomeMoreStuff -> Some More Stuff
123SomeWords -> 123 Some Words
Some1Words -> Some 1 Words
Some1234Words -> Some 1234 Words
```

as you can see on Ideone: http://ideone.com/KE64z

---

### edit

Perhaps a more intuitive way would be to globally match the parts you're interested in (either numbers: `\d+`, or capitalized words: `[A-Z][a-z]*`) and `join(' ')` these together:

```js
for (var i in tests) {
  print(tests[i].match(/\d+|[A-Z][a-z]*/g).join(' '));
}
```

which would result in the same output.

Note that my examples only take ascii letters in account: words like `café` would not work because of the `é`!